# How to provoke "Application not responding"

Tags: java, c, windows, visual-c++

For testing purposes I need to write a program that will put the famous "Application not responding" message on screen.
I don't know how I'd provoke that.

What is the quickest and easiest way to do this? Preferably either C/C++ or Java

Comment: Try a very long thread sleep operation. You could also do an infinite loop which does nothing, but this may get optimized away. No idea if it will work, but it is a good start.

Comment: An infinite loop should do fine.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any windowing program at all? If you have a program that uses windows, you merely need to stop it from responding. If you do not have such a program, you have to find a primer on writing such programs and get at least the basic code and build instructions for them.

Answer (score 3):

In the Windows API, a GUI program gets input from the OS through *messages* and it has to receive and dispatch those messages in a [message loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows). Anything happening (mouse movement/click, key press, but also things like a request to quit the application) is delivered as a message.

With every *window* created, you can attach a callback function that actually handles the messages relevant to that window (note that every GUI element is a *window*, like e.g. a button or a text input field). This callback is called a [*window procedure*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-window-procedures) in the Windows API.

The message "Application not responding" is shown by the OS when an application fails to process messages in time. So somewhere in your code, you just have to stop processing messages to provoke it, for example, you could intentionally enter an infinite loop in your message loop or in a window procedure.

Now, if you're coding in Java or using some GUI toolkit (e.g. GTK) in C, you won't write your own message loop and window procedures, the framework/toolkit provides these for you, giving you an abstract higher-level interface. Whether or not you can provoke a non-responding application depends on the design of the framework. You basically need to hog the "UI Thread" (e.g. execute an infinite loop in the main thread that normally processes the messages, so it can't do its work).

If this message is shown because of a buggy application, the bug is doing something in the main thread that a) loops infinitely, b) blocks infinitely or c) enters a deadlock. You should never do something in the main/UI thread of a win32 application that doesn't finish promptly. Or, more generally, you should never do something like that in the thread that handles events / processes messages in any GUI program.